# Using Java method's returned List as output in another method of another project

Tags: java, list, dependencies, return, testcase

I have a Java class called `TestInfoFinder` in `Project1` that extends TestCase as below:

```
public class TestInfoFinder extends TestCase {

    private ClassFinder classFinderService = null;

    public void setUp() {
        classFinderService = new ClassFinderService();
    }

    public List<Integer> testFindAnnotatedClassByPackage() throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {

        String pattern = "\\bid\\b=\\[(.+?)\\]";
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        List<String> classFilePaths = classFinderService.findAnnotatedClassesInPackage("com.mobile.tests", TestInfo.class);
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
        set.addAll(classFilePaths);
        classFilePaths.clear();
        classFilePaths.addAll(set);

        List<Integer> myListIntegers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (String ids : classFilePaths) {
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(ids);
            while (m.find()) {
                myListIntegers.add(Integer.parseInt(m.group()));
            }
        }

        for(int str: myListIntegers)
        {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
        return myListIntegers;
    }
}
```

Uses `ClassFinderService` class and its method `findAnnotatedClassesInPackage()` and this class is in another project `Project2` and `not Project1`.

`TestInfoFinder` class initially `finds annotations` in the package `com.mobile.tests` and then creates a list called `classFilePaths`. Then I convert these String values of the classFilePaths list into the integer ones(which is what I want) and I store them in `myListIntegers` list. Above all is the part of first Java project say `Project1`

Now, I have another project say `Project2` that has a class called Integration.java and it has a method as:

```
public static String addRun() {
........
...
List<Integer> cases = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int index=0; index < myListIntegers.length; index++)
        {
            cases.add(myListIntegers[index]);
        }
}
```

In above snippet, `myListIntegers` should come from my `Project1's` class `returned List (from TestInfoFinder class)`

For above scenario of Project1 and Project2, how can I use the `returned list` from `Project1` into the `Project 2`? Also, is there a better approach to modify the class `TestInfoFinder` in Project1 (as of now, I have to run the entire class to get the list, rather something else would be better for my objective)?

Answer (score 0):

This can be resolved

1) If you create a list as a class variable and assign the returned list to the  class variable.

2)In project 2 you need to have the reference of the classs and try yo get the list from the reference.